# -bash: ask: command not found

Tags: amazon-web-services, alexa-skills-kit

**I have mac and was trying to install Alexa cli with below command:**

```
sudo npm install -g ask-cli
```

My installation was showing successful but it was giving me below error on ask --version :

> -bash: ask: command not found

**I am using node version > 12**

Can any one help ?

Answer (score 0):

> I googled lot but could not found the answer. Got frustrated. So
>   finally thought of putting.

I have mac and was trying to install Alexa cli with below command:

sudo npm install -g ask-cli

My installation was showing successful but it was giving me below error on ask --version :

-bash: ask: command not found

I was using node version > 12

Finally after almost 6 hours of RnD i could solve this error by downgrading node to version 8

**Below are the detailes what i did:**

> THis was my prev version which was giving error

Anands-MacBook-Air:~ anand$ node -v
v13.6.0

**How to downgrade to lower version of node :**

Anands-MacBook-Air:~ anand$ sudo npm cache clean -f

npm WARN using --force I sure hope you know what you are doing.

Anands-MacBook-Air:~ anand$ sudo npm install -g n

/usr/local/bin/n -> /usr/local/lib/node_modules/n/bin/n
+ n@6.1.3

updated 1 package in 27.206s

Anands-MacBook-Air:~ anand$ sudo n 8 5.8

installing : node-v8.17.0
       mkdir : /usr/local/n/versions/node/8.17.0
       fetch : https://nodejs.org/dist/v8.17.0/node-v8.17.0-darwin-x64.tar.gz
   installed : v8.17.0 (with npm 6.13.4)

Anands-MacBook-Air:~ anand$ node -v

> v8.17.0

**Then did below :**

Anands-MacBook-Air:~ anand$ sudo npm install -g ask-cli

Anands-MacBook-Air:~ anand$ ask --version

1.7.22

Anands-MacBook-Air:~ anand$

> Hope it will help someone.

Answer (score 0):

If you use nvm, you might need to install it on your current Node.js version.

Answer (score 0):

Exiting out of the terminal session and opening up a new terminal session solved this for me on MacOS.